# Does the request scope have a tag for matching lifetime?

Tags: asp.net-core, autofac

Using Autofac in ASP.NET Core 1.0.

I want to be able to use `InstancePerMatchingLifetimeScope()` on my per-request scoped registrations, so that if a dependency can't be resolved from the intended lifetime scope I will get an error, rather than a fallback to the root lifetime scope which leads to subtle runtime errors that are hard to trace.

However, I don't know what tag to use - in prior versions of ASP.NET it would have been something like "AutofacWebRequest", but that doesn't work anymore.

Is there a way to access a named scope for ASP.NET Core for matching? Or, failing that, is there some other solution to this problem?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Registrations are mandatory in (ASP).NET Core. If you don't register an dependency it won't be resolved. You do register a scope with `.AddScoped<T, TImp>()`. Anything beyond that is to be provided by the 3rd party container, i.e. via extension methods or overloads to `AddSingleton()`  and I don't see them having extension methods for `IServiceCollection` in https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/blob/develop/src/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/AutofacRegistration.cs

Comment: The issue is if I have a singleton dependency that requires a request-scoped dependency - the request-scoped dependency will still be injected but it will be resolved from the parent root lifetime scope, so therefore it isn't correctly scoped, but the code that consumes the dependency can't know that. I want this to be an automatic error at runtime, hence why I wanted to try and force lifetime scopes to be explicit using matching, but it looks like that's not possible in .NET Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no tag on the request scope in .NET Core because Autofac isn't in charge of creating the request scope anymore. There is no workaround for it. [See the docs here.](http://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html)

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'm going to have to be very careful with my registrations then.